# regular expression to extract a string with ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as below

```
"The Big Bang Theory - Season 1"
```

I want to extract any string before `"- Season 1"` which is basically a show name. How do I do it with regex in ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead assertion like below. Below positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by the string `- Season 1`

```
.*(?=- Season 1)
```

Example:

```
> "The Big Bang Theory - Season 1".match(/.*(?=- Season 1)/)
=> #<MatchData "The Big Bang Theory ">
> "The Big Bang Theory - Season 1".match(/.*(?= - Season 1)/)
=> #<MatchData "The Big Bang Theory">
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression matches everything until the last `-`

```
.+?(?=-)
```

[Here it is in action](http://rubular.com/r/sCGLEFCyGg)